# Does Anypoint studio have a plugin for debugging mule files in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to debug through my code that contains mule and various XML files in Intellij. I was hoping to know if there was a Plugin for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mule-intellij Plugin

Reference Urls:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8212?pr=

https://github.com/machaval/mule-intellij-plugins

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/1777/moving-from-mule-studio-to-intellij.html

My entire project coupled with both Front end application and with Mule - maven based( I suppose to work both with Intellij and also Anypoint).Each and every application have its own POM. When i work with individual Mule application, will import apps as maven based. Anypoint studio is best to work on Mule interfaces compare to Intellij.
When it comes to front end application, used Intellij.

When  working on very large project ( both front end and Mule) if you try to import  entire project in Anypoint- It hangs. Those cases Intellij is best to import as Module( easy search, code monitor with Jira history etc).

I switch Intellij and Mule studio case by case.

After Installing Mule-intelij plugin. Could see Mule configuration xml marked as 'M'. Easy to run as Maven project and also Junit test cases.

I have installed old version of plugin where I can only debug Mule-Java application( not Mule configurable xml).Ctr+tab will show all the options as like AnyPoint. But you cant see Mule GUI or Drag and Drop feature here.

In the above mentioned first URL, new plugin version shows debug point in Mule configuration example. You can give it a go.